# XmlPullParser for a xml on sdcard does not ignore whitespaces

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I am reading the same XML using XmlPullParser either from embedded resource of the app or from SD. The problem is that when I read xml from resource whitespaces are ignored but for xml on sdcard are not ignored.

Here is how I create PullParser for xml in resource (further pulling code is common for both cases)

```
XmlPullParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(resId);
```

And here I create parser for xml on sdcard

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);

parser.setInput(fileReader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The XML *resources* inside your .apk are compiled to a binary format during the build process. This may also trim away "unnecessary" whitespaces. To avoid this compilation you can put your XML resource into the `assets` folder and read your XML from there.

`context.getResources().getXml(resId);` will then of course not work anymore; your asset will not have a resource id assigned. You'll have to use the original filename.

*Edit:*

Documentation for [getXml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml%28int%29) says:

> The XmlPullParser implementation returned here has some limited
>   functionality. In particular, you can't change its input, and only
>   high-level parsing events are available (since the document was
>   pre-parsed for you at build time, which involved merging text and
>   stripping comments).

Comment: Ok. So that means that resource simply does not have those whitespaces in runtime. I would prefer to read ignoring whitespaces then placing file to asset. So my question is: how to force XmlPullParser to ignore whitespaces, comments?

Comment: Ignoring comments is easy using nextToken(). I could not find any information regarding whitespace collpasing in *XmlPullParser*, though. Maybe you need to implement it yourself or find another implementation of that specific funtionality.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may helps you ::

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#nextToken%28%29